# Get the number of ip between a series of dates with jdbctemplate

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, date, jdbctemplate, localdatetime

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    ip VARCHAR(39) NOT NULL, -- 7+8x4=39
    data TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT client_pk PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT client_uk UNIQUE (ip)
);
```

I would like to search for the number of records that are between 2 distinct dates:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Long trovaIpTraDateEdOre(LocalDateTime dataOraInizialeInclusa, LocalDateTime dataOraFinaleEsclusa) {
    try{
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client WHERE data >= TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ? AND data < TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ?;";
        int[] tipi = {Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE, Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE};
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Long.class, tipi);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I run this query I get 7 so the problem is elsewhere:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client WHERE data >= TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2021-10-07T00:00' AND data < TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2022-01-01T00:00';
```

I don't understand how to handle LocalDateTime.

I get 'null'. Inside the 'try' loop I get:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client WHERE data >= TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ? AND data < TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ?;]; Nessun valore specificato come parametro 2.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Nessun valore specificato come parametro 2.
```

Comment: what's the error you got?

Comment: I get org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException. I added the error to the post.

Comment: You should use `java.time.OffsetDatetime` for jdbc type TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE, refer to [jdbc specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-eval-spec/index.html) B.4 Java Object Types Mapped to JDBC Types

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, I made this change but I don't solve: public Long trovaIpTraDateEdOre(OffsetDateTime dataOraInizialeInclusa, OffsetDateTime dataOraFinaleEsclusa) {
I forgot something? I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is not using the parameters you're passing through `dataOraInizialeInclusa` and `dataOraFinaleEsclusa`. You will need to rewrite it to something like this:

```java
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client WHERE data >= :from AND data < :to";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("from", dataOraInizialeInclusa);
params.put("to", dataOraFinaleEsclusa);
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, params, Integer.class);
```

I'm returning an Integer, as I don't know if `Long` will work or not (I presume it will), and as you're returning a count `Integer` would make more sense (imo). You don't need to add a cast to the SQL query as the postgres jdbc driver *should* infer the correct data type as long as you're not using too old a version.